# Arduino UNO with Sparkfun MP3 Trigger

Tags: arduino-uno

I have a basic mp3 trigger with arduino uno setup:

Trigger - https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11029

Arduino Uno code:

```
#include <MP3Trigger.h>

//  Script Function:  RobertSonics mp3trigger (v2) paired with an Arduino UNO
//  
//  Jumper Connections:   UNO  ------  mp3trigger (v2)
//             (UNO RX)     0  ------  TX
//             (UNO TX)     1  ------  RX
//             (Ground)   GND  ------  GND
//           (+5 volts)    5v  ------  USBVCC

#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
void setup(){
    Serial.begin(38400);    // Standard for mp3trigger  
    Serial.print("t");
    Serial.write(1);
    delay(50000);    
}


void loop()
{

}
```

I can't get it to play any tracks. The response in the Serial monitor just says tt

Answer (score 1):

So, from the beginning:

1. Have you got data on you SD card and is it is FT16 or FAT32 format?
2. Is the MP3 status light giving any indication of life?
3. Does the MP3 card detect when you start it up without the SD card in (One long flash).
4. Do you have a data file named "001SomethingOrOther.MP3"?
5. Have you tried the command "v" 0x00?
6. Have you tried the commands "S0" and "S1"?
7. Have you looked at the sample data on http://robertsonics.com/mp3-trigger-support/?

Hope that helps, an please post your finding, because mine arrives next week :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it working yesterday, and by accident!!!! Sorry it was not sooner, hope you had better luck with it. In any case if anyone wants to know what I did, you can read about it here. 
https://forum.sparkfun.com/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=44292